# uniform distribution and deductible

Tags: probability

Losses covered by a flood insurance policy are uniformly distributed on the interval [0,
2]. The insurer pays the amount of the loss in excess of a deductible d.
The probability that the insurer pays at least 1.20 on a random loss is 0.30.
Calculate the probability that the insurer pays at least 1.44 on a random loss.

Step 1
find distribution of y, if x is uniform $[0,2]$ and $y=x-d$ then y is uniform from $[0,2-d]$.

Is this first step correct?

Solution is $0.18$

Comment: I would have thought that the insurer's payment  $y$ had a positive probability of being $0$.  But conditional on $y$ being positive then I think you are correct that it would then be uniform on $[0,2-d]$

Answer (score 5):

No.  The distribution of $Y$, the amount paid by the insurer on a loss $X \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(0,2)$, is given by $$Y = (X-d)_+ = \max(X-d, 0) = \begin{cases} X - d, & X > d \\ 0, & X \le d. \end{cases}$$  Then we are given $$\Pr[Y \ge 1.2] = 0.3,$$ which in terms of the original loss $X$, implies $$\Pr[X \ge 1.2 + d] = 0.3.$$  Since $X$ is uniform on $[0,2]$ with survival function $S_X(x) = 1 - \frac{x}{2}$, it follows that $$1 - \frac{1.2 + d}{2} = 0.3,$$ or $d = 0.2$.  Then to calculate the probability of the insurer paying at least $1.44$, we compute $$\Pr[Y \ge 1.44] = \Pr[X > 1.44 + d].$$

Comment: thanks so can we ever assume that if x is uniform and y is a function of x that y must also be uniform?I'm just so confused because I seen this on a different problem.

Comment: $Y$ is not uniform.  $Y$ has a mixed distribution in the sense that there is a discrete probability mass at $Y = 0$, and a continuous density on $(0, 2-d]$.

Comment: okay make sense now thanks for all the help